# jMeter CSV_Data_Set config and XML dynamic binding

Tags: jmeter

I am primarily using  JMeter -CSV_Data_Config element to bind csv data with a XML template  as shown below.
This works beautifully when the data in the excel cells are static ie.. know set of columns. eg. 6 cols in csv file bind to 6 variables in XML file.

Lets say end user decides to have 15 cells of data in the csv file. Can i make the jMeter script dynamic to add new XML elements eg.Item with new attributes based on the number of cells in the csv file ?

I think a beanShell script might help if not ? not sure how .. any help -much appreciated !

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use the following approach for getting data from CSV file with unknown number of columns:

- [User Defined Variables](http://blazemeter.com/blog/afternoon-delightuser-defined-variablesavoid-code-duplication) (defined variable `N` with the value of `0`)
- [While Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)

  - [Counter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Counter) (Start: 1, Increment: 1, Reference Name: N)
  - Samplers with data-driven logic

and use the following line as condition for the While Controller

```
${__javaScript("${__CSVRead(/path/to/your/file.csv,${N})}"!="",)}
```

See [__CSVRead()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__CSVRead) function documentation for more details.